# how to get log from attendance machine in powerbuilder?

Tags: powerbuilder

I'd like guidance on retrieving attendance logs from an attendance machine using PowerBuilder. Additionally, I need assistance on utilizing the zkemkeeper.dll for this purpose.

Thank you.

** tried to use the following code :**

```
int dwTMachine, dwEnrollNumber,dwEMachineNumber,dwVerifyMode
int dwInOutMode,dwYear,dwMonth,dwDay,dwHour,dwMinute
int i
i=1
if main.ZKEM.object.ReadGeneralLogData(machineNum) then
   do while main.ZKEM.object.GetGeneralLogData(MachineNum,ref dwTMachine,ref dwEnrollNumber,ref dwEMachineNumber,ref dwVerifyMode,ref  dwInOutMode,ref dwYear,ref dwMonth,ref dwDay,ref dwHour,ref dwMinute)
        listviewitem l_lvi
        lv_log.AddItem(l_lvi)
        lv_log.SetItem(i,1,string(i))
        lv_log.SetItem(i,2,string(dwEnrollNumber))
        lv_log.SetItem(i,4,string(dwVerifyMode))
        lv_log.SetItem(i,5,string(MachineNum))
        lv_log.SetItem(i,6,string(dwInOutMode))
        
        i=i+1
        
    loop 
end if
```

**But it gives me the following error message:
Error calling external object function getgenerallogdata**

Answer (score 0):

Are the methods in the dll exposed? In general you would use COM to communicate with external resources like this.  You could write a COM wrapper for the dll (in C# for example) and then call the methods needed from that.

Comment: Thank you for your input and suggestion. However, the methods in the DLL are not currently exposed. While COM could be used for communication with external resources, in this specific scenario, there are no exposed methods in the DLL. I appreciate your cooperation and willingness to assist.